# Flash not opening links on click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, banner-ads

I created this banner with Flash and I need that on click it opens a web page.

I used this Actionscript 3.0 code...

```
link_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openurl);

function openurl(event:MouseEvent):void {
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.festivity.it");
navigateToURL(url, "_blank");
}
```

BUT it's not working!

WHYYYYY?!

I tried setting it on the timeline and also on a button, but nothing changed.

Whenever I click on the button... nothing happens, but sometimes a message opens with a security alert.

Thanks.

Chiara

Comment: If you could post more of your code, I might be able to help, but did you actually add the button via an addChild(link_btn); call?

EDIT: Just realized you are using Flash IDE, and not FlashBuilder, so my question might not be of much use.

Comment: There's not much info here to help with, but a common problem with links is forgetting to import flash.net.navigateToURL

Comment: Yeyyyyy! Jason! It's working! Thanks a lot! It was just a settings problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your publish settings enable network access from *"local playback security"*:

[image: publish-settings]

Answer (score 2):

I have spent hours and hours working with the action code snippets.  My head was practically bleeding, trying to figure out why my simple Go-To-URL action script wasn't working.  I've been using a much older version of Flash for ten years.  The "local playback security" setting was the problem, and it was not mentioned in any of the Adobe forums that I visited.  What a frustrating "feature".