# Adobe Flash Player Security Error

Tags: flash, adobe, settings

I made a game in adobe flash cs5 and when I preview it in adobe flash it works perfectly, When I run it from the .swf in my folder I keep getting this error!

[image: error]

Clicking Ok does nothing, and clicking Settings is also useless, Just opens up another window about data storage! Thats useless, I tried everything in that window.

Comment: Try to change the Publish settings (Advanced) : Local playback security : Access to network only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash not working in browser but works fine on computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302857/flash-not-working-in-browser-but-works-fine-on-computer)